# Converting date from excel to matlab in multiple fields

Tags: excel, matlab, datetime, data-conversion

I have a structure (gilts) in matlab with many fields (gilt_name). The structure is an imported workbook from excel, and each field corresponds to a worksheet in that workbook. Each worksheet is a time series of dates and corresponding prices of gilts. I converted the dates in excel to strings before importing into matlab as instructed in [When to Convert Dates from Excel Files](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/import_export/f5-100860.html#br0xp1s). But how do I apply this conversion to many fields simultaneously in matlab? I have hundreds of arrays of data corresponding to each gilt_name and it would save me lot of time.
Many thanks.

Comment: it would be helpful if you give a concrete example of how the variable are stored (matrix/cell-array, ...). Show us the code you use to import the data and an extract of the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say we had an Excel spreadsheet containing three sheets, each contains a series of dates and some corresponding values:

[image: excel]

Consider the following code to import the data into MATLAB:

```
%# for each of the three sheets
data = cell(3,1);
for i=1:3
    %# read the sheet as unprocessed data (both text and numeric)
    [~,~,raw] = xlsread('data.xlsx', i);

    %# parse strings as serial dates and combine into a matrix
    data{i} = [datenum(raw(:,1),'dd/mm/yyyy') cell2mat(raw(:,2))];
end
```

Now each cell in the cell array `data` has the data of the i-th sheet. Dates are represented as serial date numbers. For example we can plot the first time series as:

```
plot(data{1}(:,1), data{1}(:,2))
datetick('x', 'dd', 'keepticks')
xlabel('days'), ylabel('prices')
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: forgot to say, you can always go back to string representation using DATESTR function: `datestr(data{1}(:,1))`

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can make a list of your field names

```
names = fieldnames(gilts)
```

And then all you need to do is cycle through in a for loop accessing the names variable by an incremental counter.

For instance,

```
names = fieldnames(gilts);
for i = 1 : length(gilts),
   n = [gilts(i,1). 'names(i)' (:,:)];
   eval(n); % and do what you need to do
end
```

So this way you can index the strings in "names" as the fields of gilts.

Comment: no need for the EVAL call (in fact try to always avoid it); MATLAB structures support [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br1v5cc-1.html): `gilts(m).(names{n})`